# Dir.new(".").each{}でeachが渡す順番と渡すものを知りたい

Tags: ruby

Rubyがミニツクっていうサイトでruby技術者認定試験対策の問題を解いているのですが、ドリル5の問題11の解説を読みながら、1~4行目までのコードの意味はわかるのですが、5行目のDir.new(".").each{}構文でeachがblockに渡す順番と渡すべきものを解説を読んでも理解できないので、教えて欲しいです。あと、ディレクトリの各エントリとはどう意味ですか。ファイル名とか個々の記事とかのことをエントリは指すみたいですけど、そういう意味ですか。わからない質問してたらすいません。

Comment: 問題のページはこれ http://www.minituku.net/courses/1049510743/contents/890325943.html でしょうか。URLも質問中に含めておいた方がいいと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。このサイトで初めて投稿するので、urlを貼ること、わかっていませんでした。次回質問する時は、参考としてurlも載せておきますね。そのurl先のサイトが問題のページに当たるものです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dir#each`が返すものは「物理エントリー」順に並んだファイル名です。
つまり、`ls -f`したのと同じ結果が帰ってきます。決して不定ではありません。

エントリーというのは、そのディレクトリーないに存在するファイルやフォルダー一つ一つのことを言います。ディレクトリー構造に「登録」されるのでエントリーな訳です。

Comment: 物理エントリーがわからないのですがなんですか？受け取ったエントリーが表示される順番は . python ruby ..でどう考えても最初に . が来てその後にpython ruby ..が来る意味がわかりません。

Comment: あるディレクトリーの下にどんなファイルがあって、それがディスクシステムのどこから始まって、どれ位の長さか？（実際はもっと複雑です）というテーブルというかデータベース的なものがないと、ディレクトリーの下にあるファイルを管理出来ませんよね？それが（物理）エントリーです。そこに書かれたものを書かれた順番に返すので、考えればどういう順番で登録されたかが解るという話では無いと思います。`ls`等はオプションがなければエントリーの内容をソートして返すので普段はエントリーにどんな順番で書かれたか？を意識することがないんです。`man ls`にも、`-f`オプションはソートしないで出力すると書かれていますので、いくつかのディレクトリーで、`Dir#each`と`ls -f`した結果を見比べて、そういうものだと思うしかないと思います

Comment: 物理エントリーはディレクトリーの下にあるファイルを管理するデータベース的なもので、書かれた順番次第で渡す順番は決まるということですね。無知な僕でも物理エントリーのことがよくわかりました。

Answer (score 0):

`Dir#each` がブロックに渡すものはディレクトリ内のファイル名/ディレクトリ名の文字列です。順番は不定です。<s>たいていの場合は `.`, `..` が先頭に来ると思いますが。</s>(そうでもないみたいでした)

エントリというのはディレクトリ内のファイル/ディレクトリを指しています。

Rubyのマニュアルも読んでみた方がいいと思います。

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/Dir.html#I_EACH